# swapping tuple values to compare two numbers

Tags: python, tuples

I have a unique situation where I need to compare two number strings.

Two input strings `'7771'`, `'7788'`.

The use case is as such if three or four digits are equal, then it is considered bigger than the second number. For the above case, since it has three '7's, it is considered bigger than 7788.

I need to swap tuple values without using the following code.

```
m1 =  [(t[1], t[0]) for t in l1]
```

---

```
from collections import Counter
def compare(s1,s2):
    l1 = sorted(Counter(s1).items(), key = lambda k: (-int(k[1]), -int(k[0])))
    l2 = sorted(Counter(s2).items(), key = lambda k: (-int(k[1]), -int(k[0])))
```

> l1 = [('7', 3), ('1', 1)]
>     l2 = [('8', 2), ('7', 2)]

I need l1 = [(3,'7'), (1,'1')] and l2 = [(2,'7'), (2,'8')]

---

```
if m1 == m2:
    print "Equal"
elif m1 < m2:
    print "First number is bigger than second"
else:
    print "Second number is bigger"
```

Comment: Maybe you can get the most repeated value `print(Counter('7771').most_common(1))`, with this value you can realize a comparation no ?

Comment: Wha do you exactly mean by _"swap tuple values..."_ in this particular problem?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: What's the "biggest" out of `'77788'`, and `'88877'`?

Comment: @wim - It is going to be 88877

Comment: @paddu  could you explain why?

Comment: 888 - Three '8's and two 7 is bigger than three '7's and two eights

Comment: Just repeating your answer again doesn't explain why.  What's the "biggest" out of "2222111" and "33322" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear what should be the correct behavior of the code and so I will limit myself to answering the question *"I need `l1 = [(3,'7'), (1,'1')] and l2 = [(2,'7'), (2,'8')]`"*.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
l1 = sorted([i[::-1] for i in Counter(s1).items()], reverse=True)
```

or

```
c1 = Counter(s1)
l1 = sorted(zip(c1.values(), c1.keys()), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks and I liked the second solution

Comment: can't you just sort with `reverse=True` instead of that gnarly lambda?

Comment: @wim While I was not focused on optimizing *that* part of the code, you are definitely right and please edit my answer so that you can get some credit for this.

Comment: @wim I edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion. Thanks!